# How to copy a char* to a const char*?

Tags: c

I have a function that can not be modified that returns a char*.
Is it possible to call this function and store the returned value within a structure as a const char*?

I want to be able to do the following:

```
char * function(void);

struct myStruct
{
    const char *myVal;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *value = function();
    struct myStruct *s = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
    s->myVal = value;  // I want to be able to assign the value and
                       // immediately free value as per the next line.
    free(value);

    // now do some other stuff with myStruct

    // eventually free s
    free(s)

    return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to assign "value" to s->myVal and then immediately free value without losing what was stored in s->myVal as if s->myVal contained a string literal.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you `free` the memory, it's gone.

Comment: You are missing a `*` in the declaration of `s`.

Comment: Please read a good C book, once again, from beginning.

Comment: If you're OK with POSIX, you can use `strdup()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh what can be a use case? Can you think of any valid scenario where `value` can't be directly used, given that he wants to free in the next line.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya maybe another call to `value = function();`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh that should still be fine without the free right? After assigning it to `s->myVal`. Won't lead to a leak.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I believe `function()` is responsible for `malloc()`-ing, so without free, yes, you have a leak there.

Comment: @SouravGhosh What I meant is `s->myVal = value;` and then `value = function1();` This should be fine?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yep, you're right. I don't know what I was seeing...

Comment: Are `function1()` and `function()` supposed to have the same function name?

Comment: @chux updated thanks

Comment: "Is it possible to call this function and store the returned value within a structure as a const char*?" Do you want to store a copy of the pointer, then yes, that is easy.  Do you want to store a copy of the data pointed to by the `char *`, assuming it points to a _string_, yes that is easy, `strdup()`.  Or do you want something else?  Also, importaant, how long to your want that copy to last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OP wants is to not have to free the string in myStruct. He also has an upper limit on the maximum length of the string.

So the other solution is to make myVal as an array inside myStruct.

So definition of myStruct will be

```
struct myStruct
{
    char myVal[MAX_LENGTH];
};
```

And the copy will have to be made using
    s->myVal[0] = '\0';
    strncat(s->myVal, value, MAX_LENGTH);

(@chux has explained `strncat` on an empty string is the most efficient way of copying the string)

Then you can free `value` and wont have to free the string in s, just s whenever it is done.

```
free(value);
```

Other errors

```
struct myStruct s ---> struct myStruct *s
```

Comment: I want to not have to free myVal, that is why myVal is declared as a const char *.  I want to be able to store value within myVal like it was a string literal? and not have to worry about freeing myVal.  I'm not sure if that is possible though ...

Comment: In that case if there is an upper limit on the length of the string, you can make it as an char array inside myStruct. So it will be freed with the struct.

Comment: so myVal becomes const char[MAX_LENGTH]?

Comment: would the assignment still be s->myVal = value?

Comment: No, you will have to copy by value. So it will be `strncpy(s->myVal, value, MAX_LENGTH-1);`

Comment: and when i free value, will s->myVal still hold what value used to be?

Comment: Yes you can free `value` and s->myVal will be intact and usable. You will just have to free s since that is `malloc`'d. If s local, you won't have to do that too.

Comment: @Koi, note, myVal is not `const char[]` but `char[]`, you cannot make it const char and then copy stuff to it.

Comment: @Koi: defining `myVal` as `const char *` doesn't relieve you of the responsibility for calling `free` on it. It just means you can't change the value of the memory it points to, although you can change the pointer itself (which is why you can assign a value to the pointer). Best of luck.

Comment: @Koi you can make the entire struct const if you want. SO that the string cannot me modified by other routines. This can me done by declaring `s` as pointer to a normal struct, copy the value and then cast it as const struct myStruct * into another variable say `t`.

Comment: `strncpy(s->myVal, value, MAX_LENGTH-1);` is insufficient to insure `s->myVal` is a _string_.  `s->myVal` may lack a _null character_.

Comment: @chux `snprintf(s->myVal, MAX_LENGTH-1, "%s", value);`  better?

Comment: @chux other option I can think of is `strncpy(s->myVal, value, MAX_LENGTH-1); s->myVal[MAX_LENGTH-1] = '\0';`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Assuming you mean `sscanf_s()` and not `ncanf_s()`, `MAX_LENGTH-1` should be type `rsize_t`, not `int` and the -1 is not needed.  The return value needs to be check to handle errors.  An alternative is `s->myVal[0] = 0; strncat(s->myVal, value, sizeof s->myVal);`

Comment: @chux, I realized that and removed the `sscanf_s()`. Also I don't think `sscanf_s` is standard. *I genuinely don't know*

Comment: The `strncpy(s->myVal, value, MAX_LENGTH-1);
s->myVal[MAX_LENGTH-1] = '\0';` takes `MAX_LENGTH` operations. `s->myVal[0] = 0; strncat(s->myVal, value, sizeof s->myVal);` takes `strlen(vlaue)` operations.

Comment: @chux, Yes, strncpy pads with '\0's

Comment: `*scanf_s()` functions are part of _Annex K_ of C11 (optional stuff).

Comment: @chux is `s->myVal[0] = 0;` portable? Or should it be `'\0'`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141902/discussion-between-chux-and-ajay-brahmakshatriya).

Answer (score 3):

Yes assigning a pointer to unqualified type to a pointer variable to a qualified type

```
s->myVal = value;
```

Is allowed. You can always add restrictiions, but you can't take them away.

But you should not `free` the array, as long as you use it.

Comment: I get this but I want to avoid having to free myVal, hence declaring it a const char*. I want it to be like a string literal where I do not have to worry about deallocating memory. is this not possible?

Comment: @Koi you cannot create *string literals* on the fly. String literals are finite in number and hence do not cause leak.

Comment: If you want something deallocated at the same time as `*s`, you could foresee an array inside the `struct`, instead of a pointer. But then you'd have to have an estimate of the maximum length and to copy over the contents instead of assigning just the pointer value.